# What is the name of this series?

Tags: human-biology, immune-system

My biology teacher used to show us videos (actually animations) on the human immune system. What I remember is that one video was on a virus (represented as a purple colored sphere with spikes) that a woman (who is a part of a music band) inhales in an elevator when a man sneezes.

The documentary shows how the virus travels to her throat and enters one cell, multiplies, and spreads. Then the video shows how white blood cells and T-cells defend the body. In the end, when she drinks coffee, she leaves the virus on a coffee mug and her friend takes on that virus when he drinks from the same mug.

Other videos of the same series include a documentary on fractures, another one on obesity, another one on a disease transmitted when one eats chicken, etc. Can someone tell me what is the name of that series?

I **think** (not sure) it is a national geographic series?

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not about biology but about a video documentary. This question would be put on hold. In future, if you have such questions please use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere).

Comment: belongs on tv&movies stack exchange

Comment: Link to [meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-clarification-on-why-isnt-this-question-closed-as-not-belonging-to-biology-as?cb=1); as it serves an educational purpose in Biology I consider it to be on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[Body Story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2Uuc76DvlI)**.

<sup>--Have to add some characters for the system to be happy--</sup>